# JIRA Agile: How do I assign multiple users to a single subtask

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-agile, scrumboard

I'm using the JIRA Agile plugin.

I've created a task with a few subtasks inside it and I want to assign multiple users to one subtask.

Any idea how this is possible without [rebuilding JIRA from source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/building-jira-from-source-720411927.html) then tinkering the code?

Comment: My gut feeling is you are NOT doing agile.

Comment: @GiulioVian correct! but in this messy situation my team is in, it would be nice to have this feature

Answer (score 2):

[There is an Atlassian page that covers this topic](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/how-do-i-assign-issues-to-multiple-users-720415922.html).

The options they discuss may not match your requirements though. They seem to be focused on the situation where the users you assign to an issue are consistent and part of a group.

One option is to create a custom field of type 'group picker'. Another option is to have a user defined on JIRA that actually represents a group of users and has a mailing list email.